# Strange front end calculation bug

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, tax, bug

Every once in a while this strange bug occurs. After all the desired products are added to the cart, on the checkout page the calculations don't make sense at all (see attached screenshot).

The tax amount and subtotal both seem to be doubled, resulting in way too high of a Grand total!

When ordering the same combination of products another time, suddenly the right calculation is used and everything seems to be working fine.

I'm using Magento 1.7.0.2 and try to avoid updating to 1.8.1 during high season, so do you have any thoughts on how to fix this strange bug? No further price rules or discounts are set into place...

All support is highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: The first thing I would try to work out is if this is a display issue or if the incorrect numbers are in the database as well. If it is only a display issue you might be able to bypass the issue by NOT displaying the tax as part of the grand totals.

Comment: We've seen this before. It looks like double subtotals, but it's not. It's the subtotal of the current order and a previous cart. Check for that with customers who have the problem. If so clear your quotation order tables (sales_flat_quote and friends).

Comment: Does clearing the quotation order tables resolve this issue? For me it's unacceptable to repeatedly clear the tables after a customer complains, since in most cases they will be discouraged and leave the site without complaining... Perhaps it has something to do with the browser? Both instances occured in an outdated IE version.

Comment: It could be an outdated browser, but then you should not be able to reproduce it. We could reproduce this scenario on the test site, by resetting the user password and email and log in as the customer. Then placing another order. The corrupted cart would then always show up in the subtotals.

Comment: This should not be closed as off-topic, no matter how hard it might be to reproduce? Melvyns answer sure helped me, even if I'm still looking to find the underlaying cause of this problem.

Comment: Why was this question closed? This is very real bug in Magento, it is just hard to reproduce. My experience is that most of Magento bugs are hard to reproduce, so why have this Magento stackexchange, if most of Magento bugs are not allowed to be discussed?